# SQL Query - Amount Netting

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need help in sql query which will give me status based on below conditions -

If Text column has same values like(AAA 7 BBB) AND Amount column for that particular Entt and Text has same +ve and -ve value like(266.72), then status should be netting

If Text column has same values like (XXX 8 ZZZ )AND Amount column for that particular Entt and Text has different value either +ve or -ve like (-19.20/18.51), then status should be impossible netting.

For Rest of the records, Status should be No Netting

Thanks in advance!

```
Text    entt    Amount  Status
XXXX Y3 AT00    29160   Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    29160   Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    -29160  Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    -29160  Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    27000   Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    34408.8 No Netting
XXXX Y3 AT00    -27000  Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    34408.8 No Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    27000   Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    -29160  Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    29160   Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    -29160  Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    29160   Netting
XXXX Z4 AT00    -27000  Netting
```

Comment: Did you even try before posting the question? If so, please show what you tried specifically so we can help to correct any problems. We don't have your tables or data. It seems unreasonable to expect us to write your query from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your rules and sample data, the following should work:

```
select t.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.entt = t.entt and t2.text = t.text and
                                t2.amount = -t.amount
                         )
             then 'Netting'
             when exists  (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.entt = t.entt and t2.text = t.text and
                                t2.amount <> t.amount
                         ) 
             then 'Impossible Netting'
             else 'No Netting'
        end) as status
from t;
```

Comment: your query will fail for the data which i have updated now in above post....For "No Netting" Status, your query shows "Impossible Netting"

Comment: @baimzz . . . Remove the second `when` condition in the `case`.